# Why does the regex in validation.yml not work in Symfony2?

Tags: validation, symfony

The following configuration in `validation.yml` is supposed to validate the url field with the given regex as shown in the Symfony docs ([Basic Usage](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/Regex.html#basic-usage)).

```
MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\Example:
    properties:
        url:
            - Regex:
                pattern: "/^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)example.com\/.*/"
                message: "Must be a valid example.com URL"
```

But an error occurs, instead.

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/' ...

Removing occurrences of "/" made it work, but then it isn't the regex I need.

```
MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\Example:
        properties:
            url:
                - Regex:
                    pattern: "/^(https?:)?((w{3}\.)?)example.com.*/"
                    message: "Must be a valid example.com URL"
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: BTW, this has been observed in sf2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, the problem was the quotations enclosing the regex. I removed them and everything worked fine. I don't know why the slashes caused problems with the double quotes though.

```
MyCompany\MyBundle\Entity\Example:
    properties:
        url:
            - Regex:
                pattern: /^(https?:\/\/)?((w{3}\.)?)example.com\/.*/
                message: "Must be a valid example.com URL"
```